# Pregunta sobre la acentuación y los interrogativos

Tags: acentuación

En una frase como:

> No sé qué habrá en el examen.
>
> No sé cómo será el examen.

¿Por qué hay acentos en "que? y "como"? También, ¿cuándo se necesita un acento en los otros interrogativos cuando no hay una pregunta?

Comment: See also http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8779/why-is-there-an-interrogative-pronoun-in-this-sentence-which-is-not-a-question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

que can be used:

without accent:

- **relative pronoun**: el libro que estás leyendo
- **conjunction**: tienes que leer más

with accent

- **interrogative pronoun**: ¿Qué estás leyendo?
- **exlamation pronoun**: !Qué calor hace!

Similar rules folow **que, quien, como, cuando, donde, y porque** (**por qué** gets separated for interrogations)

In your example, *no sé qué va a salir en el examen*, you are saying that you don't know the answer to a question, but qué is part of that question. It is an interrogative pronoun too.

**No sé quién va a venir para Navidad**

Comment: In addition: Notice that, in English, this roughly implies: "qué" = "what" , "que" = "that" (or empty). And "como" ="as, like", "cómo" = "how"

Comment: @leonbloy Pero ‘que’ también puede traducirse como ‘what’, el ‘what’ cumple las funciones relatives e interrogativas en el inglés